# org-mode repeating TODO skip

Tags: org-mode

I'd love to be able to generally use repeating entries, but also have the ability to skip specific days.  example:

```
** TODO swim practice
   SCHEDULED <2013-12-18 17:30-18:30 +1w>
```

However, I know in advance there won't be a practice on 2013-12-25.  When I mark the item done, however, it will be rescheduled for 2013-12-25.  I'd love something as simple as a property like:

```
** TODO swim practice
   SCHEDULED <2013-12-18 17:30-18:30 +1w>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :EXCEPTION_SCHEDULED: <2013-12-25>
   :EXCEPTION_SCHEDULED: <2014-01-01>
   :END:
```

But, I don't see any easy way to accomplish this (except sexp's... which are painful and ugly).  I looked at writing my own hook, but the hooks for state changes are called after the state change, but before the new date has been repeated.  I thinking about catching it post-update and seeing if it matched an exception and then calling the re-scheduling routing again.

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

The function `org-class` might help.  It lets you set schedule weekly events with certain weeks or holidays skipped.  This TODO entry will schedule a class for every Wednesday between 2013-12-18 and 2014-12-31 except for weeks 1 and 52:

```
** TODO swim practice
   SCHEDULED: <%%(org-class 2013 12 18 2014 12 31 1 3 1 52) 17:30-18:30>
```

You can also do

```
** TODO swim practice
   SCHEDULED: <%%(org-class 2013 12 18 2014 12 31 1 3 'holidays) 17:30-18:30>
```

to skip any day Emacs knows to be holiday or give strings like "New Year's Day" to skip only specific holidays.